# How to add a div showing the difference between the two bar values as percentage in multi-bar chart using d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I have implemented a multi bar chart using d3. I want to add a div which shows the difference between percentage between two bars using d3. I am able to calculate and store the difference as percentage in an array. But i am not able to add the tooltip at the top of the bars. 
[Image showing the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vWbw.png)

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var data = [
        {
            "categorie": "Student", 
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": 6, 
                    "rate": "actual"
                }, 
                {
                    "value": 4, 
                    "rate": "budget"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "categorie": "Liberal Profession", 
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": 1, 
                    "rate": "actual"
                }, 
                {
                    "value": 21, 
                    "rate": "budget"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "categorie": "Salaried Staff", 
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": 3, 
                    "rate": "actual"
                }, 
                {
                    "value": 22, 
                    "rate": "budget"
                }
            ] 
        }
            ]
        }
    ]
var percentage = [];

var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.2);
var x1 = d3.scaleBand();

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x0)
    .tickSize(0);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#ca0020","#f4a582","#d5d5d5","#92c5de","#0571b0"]);

var svg = d3.select('#d3multibar').append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

function multibar(data) {
// adding list of categories to an array
        var categoriesNames = data.map(function(d) { return d.categorie; });

// adding list of rates to an array
        var rateNames = data[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.rate; });  
        data.map(function (d,i) {
           percentage[i] = (d.values[0].value - d.values[1].value)/d.values[1].value * 100
           console.log(percentage[2])
        })

        x0.domain(categoriesNames);
        x1.domain(rateNames).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(categorie) { return d3.max(categorie.values, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]); 

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);       
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .style('opacity','0')
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .style('font-weight','bold')
            .text("Value");     
        svg.select('.y').transition().duration(500).delay(1300).style('opacity','1');   
// here i am adding the bars to the chart

        var slice = svg.selectAll(".slice")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "g")
            .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.categorie) + ",0)"; });  

        slice.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d) { console.log(d.values);return d.values; })
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.rate); })
            .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
            .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.rate) })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(0); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(0); })
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).style("fill", d3.rgb(color(d.rate)).darker(2));
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).style("fill", color(d.rate));
                tooltip1.style("display", "none");
            }) 
            .on("mousemove", function(d){
                tooltip1
                  .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 + "px")
                  .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
                  .style("display", "inline-block")
                  .html(d.value)

            });
        slice.selectAll("rect")
            .transition()
            .delay(function (d) {return Math.random()*1000;})
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });       

// Here i am truing to add the div using the percentage
        var slice1 = svg.selectAll(".slice1")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "g")
            .attr("x", function(d) { console.log(x0(d.categorie)); return "translate(" + x0(d.categorie) + ",0)";})

            slice1.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d) { console.log(d.values);return d.values; })
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.rate); })
            .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())





};

multibar(data)
```

In the above code example i have calculated the percentage using the values. Now i want to add those values on top of the respective multi bar pairs as shown in the above image.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, in order for people to effectively help you with your question, It's much better if you provide the code of progress you have made or a working example by utilizing jsfiddle or SO's own code editor CTRL - M

Comment: Thank you for suggesting. I have added the code for more clarification.

Comment: Could you explain in detail how is the percentage calculated. Is it calculated between Student, Liberal Profession and Salaried Staff for red bars separate from peach bars? What is the tooltip exactly. Is it the % value and the dotted line which appears on top?

Comment: I am calculating the percentage by subtracting the value's within the value object separately for different categories. The tooltip is nothing but a div placed above each multi bar pair which shows the difference in increase or decrease of percentage of values for each respective category. We can ignore the dotted line as of now.